# Importing all worksheets from a folder into one master workbook

Tags: excel, vba, import, spreadsheet, worksheet

I've been spending time online to work out how to import worksheets from a folder and import them as their own sheets into one master workbook.

The spreadsheet is located in its own folder StatConverter with another folder named Users in the same directory.

Here it is:

```
    Dim FolderName As String
    FolderName = Environ$("userprofile") & "\OneDrive - {Redacted}\Desktop\StatConverter\Users\"
```

In the users folder, the total number of sheets varies and I would need to put the script in a loop.

On an excel forum I have found this example:

```
Sub Import()

Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = Environ$("userprofile") & "\OneDrive - {Redacted}\Desktop\StatConverter\Users\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")

Do While fileName <> ""

    Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
    
    For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
    
        total = Workbooks("import-sheets.xlsm").Worksheets.Count
        Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
        after:=Workbooks("import-sheets.xlsm").Worksheets(total)
        
        Workbooks(fileName).Close
        
        fileName = Dir()
        
    Next sheet

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I have tried to modify it to suit my needs but I cannot get this working, nor is there an error message for me to troubleshoot.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Worksheets From Multiple Files

- Try to avoid a loop whenever possible. The following should work if there are no very hidden worksheets and at least one worksheet is visible and there aren't any other hidden 'surprises'.

```vb
Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
' If it's not, tnen instead use:
'Set swb = Workbooks("import-sheets.xlsm")

Do While Filename <> ""
    With Workbooks.Open(directory & Filename)
        .Worksheets.Copy After:=swb.Sheets(swb.Sheets.Count)
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
    Filename = Dir
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
        Workbooks(fileName).Close
        
        fileName = Dir()
        
    Next sheet

Loop
```

use this.

```
        Workbooks(fileName).Close
        
    Next sheet
    fileName = Dir()
Loop
```